# A question related to normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

I am facing the following question:

Let $G$ be a domain and $0,1\in G$. Let $F$ be the family of analytic function $f$ defined on $G$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f|<2$ on $G$. Prove that there is $0<c<2$ s.t $|f(1)|<c$ for all $f\in F$.

My idea: Join $0$ and $1$ with a line, compute $\int_0^1 f'=f(1)-f(0)$ and try to estimate $|f'|$ by Cauchy's estimate, but I can't get the conclusion.

Comment: Which family is normal, and how can you exploit the normality?

Comment: I see $F$ is normal since it's (locally) bound and $F'=\{f',f\in F\}$ is also locally bound but I don't know if we can find a $c\in (0,2)$ bounds $F'$. @DanielFischer

Comment: You don't need to look at $F'$ at all. So, $F$ is normal. Recall what that means. How could you exploit that?

Comment: You mean I can use Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, then I see $\{f(1)| f\in F\}$ has compact closure in $C$, so I can get what I want. But $f(0)=0$ seems useless. @DanielFischer

Answer (score 0):

The family $F$ is normal, so a little argument shows that if the statement is false, then we may find a sequence of $f_n \in F$ such that $f_n$ converges (uniformly on compact subsets of $G$) to a holomorphic function $f$, and such that $f_n(1) \to 2$.

Then $f(1) = 2$, and $|f| \leq 2$.  The maximum modulus theorem then shows that $f$ is constant, and thus that $f = 2$ (identically).  This contradicts the fact that
$\displaystyle f(0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(0)  = 0.$

(Note that if we didn't have the requirement that the functions in $F$ satisfy
$f(0) = 0$, i.e. if we considered the larger normal family of all holomorphic $f$ on $G$ such that $|f|  < 2$, then the statement would be false.  E.g. we could just choose a sequence
of constant functions approaching $2$ from below, to see that in fact no $c$ as in the statement of the question exists.)